# How to set start value for PK in EF Core 5.0

Tags: entity-framework-core

I need set start value (100000000) for PK 'ProductID'. I use this code:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().Property(x => x.ProductID).UseIdentityColumn(100000000, 1);
```

but in DB the value of new records is still 1,2,3

Comment: Did you recreate the table or run a migration after you added this code?

Comment: I run "update-database", the table has already been created.

Comment: Did you add a new migration?

Comment: Yes. I create new migration.

Comment: Thank you DavidG, I recreated table and all works.